# C# compiler error differences between CS0122 and CS0143

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors

Let's consider the following first example:

```
public class ClassNameExample
{
    private ClassNameExample()
    {
        //code goes here    
    }
}
```

Now, if I try to instantiate the `ClassNameExample` class from within the same assembly, I'll get an "Inaccessible due to it's protection level" compiler error message ([CS0122](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha94aebs.aspx)).

However, if I try to instantiate the `ClassNameExample` class from a different assembly, I'm getting a "The type 'class' has no constructors defined" compiler error message ([CS0143](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z6fxc01(v=vs.140).aspx))

Can someone explain why the compiler sees them different?

For reference, I've tried this in Visual Studio 2012, .NET 4.5.

Comment: In my honest opinion when you are in the same assembly compiler knows about the existence of the private constructor so it tells you that it is private. When you are in another assembly it simply doesn't know about, it just knows that the class does not expose any public constructor

Comment: My guess would be, because while compiling the same assembly the compiler sees the constructor definition but it is private and therefore inaccessible. When compiling another assembly, the compiler only sees the published interface for that assembly without even having access to the internals. In that public interface there _is_ no constructor so as far as the compiler is concerned, there is none. However, I cannot quote any reliable source so I'm happy to see someone post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to see what Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator does and to figure out where the errors are populated, but the code at the end relies on external files.

The only answer I can give you is: if you create an instance with

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance("ClassNameExample");
```

or even with  `Activator.CreateInstance("Your assembly", "ClassNameExample");`

both return null because they rely on public constructor, check the flags

```
    public object CreateInstance(string typeName)
    {
      return this.CreateInstance(typeName, false, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, (Binder) null, (object[]) null, (CultureInfo) null, (object[]) null);
    }

    Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyName, typeName, false, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.CreateInstance, (Binder) null, (object[]) null, (CultureInfo) null, (object[]) null, (Evidence) null, ref stackMark);
```